$2$nd Order Nonlinear ODE with $y'^2$ Term
I am attempting to find a closed-form solution to the differential equation $5y'^2 - 4yy'' = 0$. The substitution $y' = v$ does not appear to work here, due to the $y'^2$ term on the left hand side. How would I go about approaching this problem?

Hint: Divide through by $yy'$ then integrate

Put $ u=y/y'$ and observe that $yy"/y'^2 = 1-u'$

The substitution $y'=v$ does work:
\begin{align}
5y'^2-4yy''=0 &\implies 5v^2-4yv\frac{dv}{dy}=0 \\
&\implies v\left(5v-4y\frac{dv}{dy}\right)=0 \\
&\implies v=0\quad\text{or}\quad 5v-4y\frac{dv}{dy}=0. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Both equations in $(1)$ can be solved easily.
